# Angular 2 with typescript routing not working

Tags: asp.net-core, angular2-routing

I have an angular 2 .net core app I downloaded from: 
https://github.com/chsakell/aspnet-core-signalr-angular

I attempted to add a new module and changed the routing to this:

```html
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'another', component: AnotherComponent },
];
```

"another" being the new component. So I expect that entering: "http://localhost:5000/#/another" into the address bar should load "another" module. But this doesn't work. It loads "another" module if I link the default path which is '' to AnotherComponent. The only path that works in the default path which is ''.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? No errors display in the console.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "another module"? What do you mean by it doesnt work? errors? exceptions? some more details would be nice. Maybe reformulate your problem description a little

Comment: Look man, I put "another" in quotes every single time. How on earth do you not understand the components name is "another"

Comment: You are mixing the concepts of module and component in your question, ofc I need to ask.

Comment: Apologies, I am a little frustrated. I have come a little further and found out that when /home is hit, it works because it hits the Index action in "HomeController" where as the other pages don't have their own controllers. I essentially need to figure out how to use mvc with angular routing without having to add a new controller for each angular page

Answer (score 0):

If any one else has an issue similar to this - if you're using MVC routing alongside angular routing. The urls need to be specified for MVC as well. So when you add a new route for angular it attempts to find a controller/action that probably doesn't exist. So what I did was this:

```
      [Route("Home")]
      [Route("Home/Another")]
      [Route("Home/Start")]
      Public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

And the angular routes need to match.